# Markdown filter wraps paragraph tags with pre-tags in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, markdown, paragraphs

I have the following text (string from SQL):

```
Paragraph \n Newline \n\n Paragraph2 \n\n\n\n Paragraph3
```

This line is processed by:

```
function nl2brAndParagraphs($text) {
    $br = nl2br($text);
    $data = preg_replace('/^\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)*/i', '', $br); //Remove any whitespace and br- tags that are at the beginning of the text
$data = preg_replace('/\s*(?:<br\s*\/?>\s*)*$/i', '', $data); //Remove any whitespace and br- tags that are at the end of the text

$data = preg_replace('#(?:<br\s*/?>\s*?){2,}#','</p>
    <p>',$data); //Replace multiple line breaks with paragraphs
$data = '<p>'.$data.'</p>';
return $data;
}
```

This returns:

```
<p>Paragraph <br /> Newline </p><p> Paragraph2 </p><p></p><p> Paragraph3</p>
```

When applying a Markdown- filter (standard Michelf Markdown port) on the result, it shouldn't change anything in this case, but it returns:

```
<p>paragraph <br /> Newline </p>
<pre><code>    &lt;p&gt;
</code></pre>
<p> paragraph2 </p><p></p><p> paragraph3 </p></p>
```

The pre- formatting disappears when removing the markdown- filter or applying it before nl2brAndParagraphs. 
Anyone know why this happens and how to solve it?

****EDIT:*****
I haven't made any changes to the standard markdown code and I'm using

```
    function Markdown($text) {
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/php-markdown-lib/Michelf/Markdown.inc.php');
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/php-markdown-lib/Michelf/MarkdownExtra.inc.php');
    return \Michelf\MarkdownExtra::defaultTransform($text);
}
```

to parse the string.

Comment: Can you add code of exactly how you are using Michelf's Markdown parser?

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't set `no_markup` to `true`? (See documentation: https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/configuration/#markdown)

Comment: Added markdown usage to the question. Using default settings. Also, all <p> tags are left untouched, but it adds pre between the first and second one. (See how the p-tags between paragraph2 and 3 are unchanged)